# add is null condtion in db_update

Tags: database

I want to use db_update with condition that a specify field is null ,how can I do it?

something like

```
->condition('used_date',  'isnull','=')
```

is this correct ,if not,what is the correct condition ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://drupal.org/node/310086), there is a method just for that: [`->isNull()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!query.inc/function/QueryConditionInterface%3a%3aisNull/7)

```
$query->isNull('myfield');
// Results in (myfield IS NULL)
$query->isNotNull('myfield');
// Results in (myfield IS NOT NULL)
```